# Prove if $s_n \geq 0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ & $s_n \rightarrow s$, then $s_n^{\frac{1}{k}} \rightarrow s^\frac{1}{k} \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm totally confused. I know that I know by definition that a sequence converges if $\exists p \in X$ such that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n>N$, $d(p_n, p) < \epsilon$. A hint is to use the formula $(a-b)(a^0b^{k-1} + a^1b^{k-2} + \cdots + a^{k-1}b^0) = a^k-b^k$ and replace it with $a= s_n^{\frac{1}{k}}$ and $b=s^\frac{1}{k}$ but I really don't see how it helps.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I should edit to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the case where $s = 0$ and $s > 0$ separately.  In the latter case we have $s_n > 0$ for sufficiently large $n$.

For the second case ($s > 0$):

Hint 1 (given):

$$s_n - s = (s_n^{1/k} - s^{1/k})\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(s_n^{1/k})^j(s^{1/k})^{k-1-j}$$

Hint 2:

$$|s_n^{1/k} - s^{1/k}| = |s_n - s|\left[\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(s_n^{1/k})^j(s^{1/k})^{k-1-j}\right]^{-1}$$

Hint 3: Construct an $\epsilon - N$ argument by finding a bound for the sum. Here you use the hypothesis that $s_n \to s$, and for $n$ sufficiently large we have $$|s_n-s| < s/2 \implies -s/2 < s_n -s < s/2 \implies s_n > s/2.$$

Hence,

$$(s_n^{1/k})^j(s^{1/k})^{k-1-j} > ((s/2)^{1/k})^j(s^{1/k})^{k-1-j} = s^{j/k}2^{-j/k}s^{1 - 1/k}s^{-j/k} = s^{1 - 1/k}2^{-j/k} >  s^{1 - 1/k}2^{-1},
$$

and

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(s_n^{1/k})^j(s^{1/k})^{k-1-j} > ks^{1 - 1/k}2^{-1}.$$

Thus,

$$|s_n^{1/k} - s^{1/k}| < |s_n - s|\left[ks^{1 - 1/k}2^{-1}\right]^{-1}$$

Comment: Thanks. I understand hint 1 and hint 2. I'm assuming we want to find an upper bound for the sum. I'm a little stuck on the third hint. So we have $s_n > \frac{s}{2}$. Is this supposed to hint at a possible upper bound for the summation?

Comment: Yes -- your goal is to find an upper bound for $\left[\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(s_n^{1/k})^j(s^{1/k})^{k-1-j}\right]^{-1}$ that is independent of $n$.  For a typical term we have $(s_n^{1/k})^j(s^{1/k})^{k-1-j} > ((s/2)^{1/k})^j(s^{1/k})^{k-1-j} = s^{j/k}2^{-j/k}s^{1 - 1/k}s^{-j/k} = s^{1 - 1/k}2^{-j/k} >  s^{1 - 1/k}2^{-1}$.

Comment: There are $k$ terms in the sum, each of which has the same upper bound.  If $[ \sum \ldots ] > C$ , then $[ \sum \ldots ]^{-1} < C^{-1}$

Comment: Oh! Let me see if I'm getting this right: since it's just a summation of $s_n$ and we have $s_n > s/2$, then $1/s_n < 2/s$. and so $k \cdot 2/s$ is an upper bound because all of the sums have the same upper bound.

Comment: Almost -- we have a sum of $k$ terms involving $s_n$ each of which is bigger than $s^{1-1/k}2^{-1}$ because $s_n > s/2$. I elaborate above in the answer.

Comment: Darn. I thought I was close. Thank you for patiently walking me through this, though. I really appreciate it!

Comment: You're very welcome.  Hopefully it is clearer to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47555/discussion-between-nikitau-and-rrl).